# How to use Array attributes in sails.js model

Tags: javascript, arrays, sails.js, sails-mongo

Hi i am a new bee to sails and trying to get a model api that finally gives output as follows

```html
[ 
  { 
    "icon" : [ 
      {"name":"ico1", "ico_typ":"fb", "ico_content_URL":"someLocation"},
      {"name":"ico2", "ico_typ":"tw", "ico_content_URL":"someLocation"},
      {...}
      ]
      "createdAt":
      "updatedAt":
     
  } 
]
```

I thought i can achieve this by passing the icon attribute as an Array but the problem is it passes the whole Array as string when i load it in REST CLIENT also i could not use the validation for values inside Array like without ico_type and URL the data should not be loaded into database. So, any suggestion about use of the 'array' where i'm wrong is very appreciated, thanks so much! 
Sails_v0.11.0
MongoDB_3.0.1

Comment: what do you use to send back the response ? res.ok({}) ?

Comment: no i created an icon model and defined an attribute there {icon : { type : array, required:true}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model define a method

```
toJSON: function () {
   var obj = this.toObject();
   //say your obj.icon returns something like `'[{"name":"ico1","ico_typ":"fb","ico_content_URL":"someLocation"},{"name":"ico2","ico_typ":"tw","ico_content_URL":"someLocation"}]'`
   obj.icon = JSON.parse(obj.icon)
   return obj;
},
```

Comment: Yes That's Perfectly works but i also need to validate the contents inside the array like the array must be created only if it has the valid URL

Comment: thats another issue, You can add something like `beforeCreate: function (values, next) {
   ....
  }`

And you can accept the answer, so that other can be benefited  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the model WaterLine gave you is already an JSON format, all you need to do is to use the right way to response it.

```
res.json(model);
```

Comment: I get the result Json as i need but by aim is to use the waterline validations inside the json object. any suggestions to that?